# Merging using XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0

Below is my input XML. Here Each X_DLV_TAB_ITEM have multiple RL_DETAILS that again have multiple RL_DETAILS_ITEM. Each X_DLV_TAB_ITEM contains TYPE.

My requirement is if TYPE is same for two or more X_DLV_TAB_ITEM then only one X_DLV_TAB_ITEM should get created which will contain all the RL_DETAILS_ITEM with same TYPE and for the ones with different TYPE need to follow the rest.

INPUT:

```
<X_DLV_TAB>
    <X_DLV_TAB_ITEM>
        <TYPE>A</TYPE>
        <TRANSACTION_CODE>RC</TRANSACTION_CODE>
        <DELIVERY_ID>46689764</DELIVERY_ID>
        <NAME>46689764</NAME>
        <RL_DETAILS>
            <RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
                <DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>14460996</DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>
                <GROSS_WEIGHT>11</GROSS_WEIGHT>
                <WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>LB</WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>
                <VOLUME>0.2</VOLUME>
                <VOLUME_UOM_CODE>CF</VOLUME_UOM_CODE>
                <REQUESTED_QUANTITY>5</REQUESTED_QUANTITY>
            </RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
            <RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
                <DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>14460997</DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>
                <GROSS_WEIGHT>5.28333</GROSS_WEIGHT>
                <WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>LB</WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>
                <VOLUME>0.12</VOLUME>
                <VOLUME_UOM_CODE>CF</VOLUME_UOM_CODE>
                <REQUESTED_QUANTITY>3</REQUESTED_QUANTITY>
            </RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
        </RL_DETAILS>
    </X_DLV_TAB_ITEM>
    <X_DLV_TAB_ITEM>
        <TYPE>A</TYPE>
        <TRANSACTION_CODE>RC</TRANSACTION_CODE>
        <DELIVERY_ID>46689764</DELIVERY_ID>
        <NAME>46689764</NAME>
        <RL_DETAILS>
            <RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
                <DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>14460993</DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>
                <GROSS_WEIGHT>17.6111</GROSS_WEIGHT>
                <WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>LB</WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>
                <VOLUME>0.4</VOLUME>
                <VOLUME_UOM_CODE>CF</VOLUME_UOM_CODE>
                <REQUESTED_QUANTITY>12</REQUESTED_QUANTITY>
            </RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
            <RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
                <DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>14460994</DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>
                <GROSS_WEIGHT>33</GROSS_WEIGHT>
                <WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>LB</WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>
                <VOLUME>0.6</VOLUME>
                <VOLUME_UOM_CODE>CF</VOLUME_UOM_CODE>
                <REQUESTED_QUANTITY>15</REQUESTED_QUANTITY>
            </RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
            <RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
                <DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>14460995</DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>
                <GROSS_WEIGHT>26.4</GROSS_WEIGHT>
                <WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>LB</WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>
                <VOLUME>0.48</VOLUME>
                <VOLUME_UOM_CODE>CF</VOLUME_UOM_CODE>
                <REQUESTED_QUANTITY>10</REQUESTED_QUANTITY>
            </RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
        </RL_DETAILS>
    </X_DLV_TAB_ITEM>
    <X_DLV_TAB_ITEM>
        <TYPE>B</TYPE>
        <TRANSACTION_CODE>RC</TRANSACTION_CODE>
        <DELIVERY_ID>46689766</DELIVERY_ID>
        <NAME>46689766</NAME>
        <RL_DETAILS>
            <RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
                <DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>14460993</DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>
                <GROSS_WEIGHT>17.6111</GROSS_WEIGHT>
                <WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>LB</WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>
                <VOLUME>0.4</VOLUME>
                <VOLUME_UOM_CODE>CF</VOLUME_UOM_CODE>
                <REQUESTED_QUANTITY>10</REQUESTED_QUANTITY>
            </RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
        </RL_DETAILS>
    </X_DLV_TAB_ITEM>
    <X_DLV_TAB_ITEM>
        <TYPE>C</TYPE>
        <TRANSACTION_CODE>RC</TRANSACTION_CODE>
        <DELIVERY_ID>46689767</DELIVERY_ID>
        <NAME>46689767</NAME>
        <RL_DETAILS>
            <RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
                <DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>14460995</DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>
                <GROSS_WEIGHT>26.4</GROSS_WEIGHT>
                <WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>LB</WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>
                <VOLUME>0.48</VOLUME>
                <VOLUME_UOM_CODE>CF</VOLUME_UOM_CODE>
                <REQUESTED_QUANTITY>150</REQUESTED_QUANTITY>
            </RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
        </RL_DETAILS>
    </X_DLV_TAB_ITEM>
</X_DLV_TAB>
```

OUTPUT:

```
<X_DLV_TAB>
    <X_DLV_TAB_ITEM>
        <TYPE>A</TYPE>
        <TRANSACTION_CODE>RC</TRANSACTION_CODE>
        <DELIVERY_ID>46689764</DELIVERY_ID>
        <NAME>46689764</NAME>
        <RL_DETAILS>
            <RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
                <DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>14460996</DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>
                <GROSS_WEIGHT>11</GROSS_WEIGHT>
                <WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>LB</WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>
                <VOLUME>0.2</VOLUME>
                <VOLUME_UOM_CODE>CF</VOLUME_UOM_CODE>
                <REQUESTED_QUANTITY>5</REQUESTED_QUANTITY>
            </RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
            <RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
                <DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>14460997</DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>
                <GROSS_WEIGHT>5.28333</GROSS_WEIGHT>
                <WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>LB</WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>
                <VOLUME>0.12</VOLUME>
                <VOLUME_UOM_CODE>CF</VOLUME_UOM_CODE>
                <REQUESTED_QUANTITY>3</REQUESTED_QUANTITY>
            </RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
            <RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
                <DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>14460993</DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>
                <GROSS_WEIGHT>17.6111</GROSS_WEIGHT>
                <WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>LB</WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>
                <VOLUME>0.4</VOLUME>
                <VOLUME_UOM_CODE>CF</VOLUME_UOM_CODE>
                <REQUESTED_QUANTITY>10</REQUESTED_QUANTITY>
            </RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
            <RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
                <DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>14460994</DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>
                <GROSS_WEIGHT>33</GROSS_WEIGHT>
                <WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>LB</WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>
                <VOLUME>0.6</VOLUME>
                <VOLUME_UOM_CODE>CF</VOLUME_UOM_CODE>
                <REQUESTED_QUANTITY>15</REQUESTED_QUANTITY>
            </RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
            <RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
                <DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>14460995</DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>
                <GROSS_WEIGHT>26.4</GROSS_WEIGHT>
                <WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>LB</WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>
                <VOLUME>0.48</VOLUME>
                <VOLUME_UOM_CODE>CF</VOLUME_UOM_CODE>
                <REQUESTED_QUANTITY>12</REQUESTED_QUANTITY>
            </RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
        </RL_DETAILS>
    </X_DLV_TAB_ITEM>
    <X_DLV_TAB_ITEM>
        <TYPE>B</TYPE>
        <TRANSACTION_CODE>RC</TRANSACTION_CODE>
        <DELIVERY_ID>46689766</DELIVERY_ID>
        <NAME>46689766</NAME>
        <RL_DETAILS>
            <RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
                <DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>14460993</DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>
                <GROSS_WEIGHT>17.6111</GROSS_WEIGHT>
                <WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>LB</WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>
                <VOLUME>0.4</VOLUME>
                <VOLUME_UOM_CODE>CF</VOLUME_UOM_CODE>
                <REQUESTED_QUANTITY>10</REQUESTED_QUANTITY>
            </RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
        </RL_DETAILS>
    </X_DLV_TAB_ITEM>
    <X_DLV_TAB_ITEM>
        <TYPE>C</TYPE>
        <TRANSACTION_CODE>RC</TRANSACTION_CODE>
        <DELIVERY_ID>46689767</DELIVERY_ID>
        <NAME>46689767</NAME>
        <RL_DETAILS>
            <RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
                <DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>14460995</DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID>
                <GROSS_WEIGHT>26.4</GROSS_WEIGHT>
                <WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>LB</WEIGHT_UOM_CODE>
                <VOLUME>0.48</VOLUME>
                <VOLUME_UOM_CODE>CF</VOLUME_UOM_CODE>
                <REQUESTED_QUANTITY>150</REQUESTED_QUANTITY>
            </RL_DETAILS_ITEM>
        </RL_DETAILS>
    </X_DLV_TAB_ITEM>
</X_DLV_TAB>
```

My Code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


    <xsl:key name="first_of_source" match="X_DLV_TAB/X_DLV_TAB_ITEM[not(preceding-sibling::X_DLV_TAB_ITEM/TYPE = TYPE)]" use="TYPE"/>

    <xsl:key name="same_source" match="X_DLV_TAB/X_DLV_TAB_ITEM/RL_DETAILS" use="RL_DETAILS_ITEM"/>


    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="X_DLV_TAB">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('first_of_source', X_DLV_TAB_ITEM/TYPE)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="RL_DETAILS">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('same_source', RL_DETAILS_ITEM)/RL_DETAILS_ITEM"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this code is not generating the required output. I am using XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Could you minimize the example, please? Grouping the `X_DLV_TAB_ITEM` elements by `TYPE` is easy if you define your key as `<xsl:key name="item-by-type" match="X_DLV_TAB_ITEM" use="TYPE"/>` and follow the [Muenchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). But I am not going to analyze hundreds of code lines to learn how you want to populate the groups.

Comment: Thanks for checking @michael.hor257k. I minimized the example data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT, you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="item-by-type" match="X_DLV_TAB_ITEM" use="TYPE"/>

<xsl:template match="/X_DLV_TAB">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- create a group for each distinct TYPE -->
        <xsl:for-each select="X_DLV_TAB_ITEM[count(. | key('item-by-type', TYPE)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <!-- copy common elements -->
                <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::RL_DETAILS)]"/>
                <RL_DETAILS>
                    <!-- copy all RL_DETAILS_ITEMs of current group-->
                    <xsl:copy-of select="key('item-by-type', TYPE)/RL_DETAILS/RL_DETAILS_ITEM"/>
                </RL_DETAILS>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that this assumes that all `X_DLV_TAB_ITEM`s with the same `TYPE` have the same data, except for the contents of `RL_DETAILS`. Therefore, all data except the contents of `RL_DETAILS` is copied from the first `X_DLV_TAB_ITEM` of each group. Then the `RL_DETAILS` element is populated by the `RL_DETAILS_ITEM`s of the entire group.

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k. Even if I have different data in  **X_DLV_TAB_ITEM**s I want the first occurrence of **X_DLV_TAB_ITEM**. I have a question on this... what if the **X_DLV_TAB_ITEM** and **RL_DETAILS** are in the same hierarchy and there is more data on to of **X_DLV_TAB**. I will add that additional data if you have a chance to look at it. Thanks Maryann

Comment: It seems yo be a significantly different question - and I suggest you post it separately (and edit your question here back to its original).

Comment: Sure @michael.hor257k I will post a different question and correct back this question to its original. Thanks Maryann.